# How to detect web browser name and version?

Tags: java, user-agent

Looking for a Java library that converts `User-Agent` header into browser name and version.

I need this information in order to understand whether I can send XML+XSL to the browser, or I should do the transformation to XHTML on the server.

Comment: Take a look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493617/looking-for-a-java-user-agent-string-parser

Comment: Any library you use would have to be updated multiple times a month to work. Consider that Chrome and Firefox change versions every few months at most now. Look into parsing http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp on your own -- it's a regularly updated database of expressions for matching user agents.

Comment: I need this information in order to understand whether I can send XML+XSL to the browser, or I should do the transformation to XHTML on the server

Comment: I already answered please refer this link

[Browser and OS details][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326928/how-can-i-get-client-infomation-such-as-os-and-browser/18030465#18030465

Answer (score 1):

> I need this information in order to understand whether I can send XML+XSL to the browser, or I should do the transformation to XHTML on the server.

It seems the best approach for that is [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html).  When you run a restaurant (server), don't ask the diner (UA) what their name is, just ask them *what they want to eat* (content type)!

Comment: What content type I should expect when the browser is supporting XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @yegor256: *"What content type I should expect when the browser is supporting XSLT 2.0? "*  I don't understand.  Are you asking *'what is the content-type of XSLT?'*?  @trashgod: Thanks!