# How do I determine the default browser in Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, browser

I am designing small Java application and there is a webDriver in it. The application will collect information from a web service.

One of the requirements for this app is no particular browser dependency. That is, I don't know which browser is installed on the end user PC. As a result, I need to use the default browser. How do I do this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the browser - just load a URL? If so, then this question may have your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967451/open-a-link-in-browser-with-java-button

Comment: Check the user agent. It should be in your HTTP request:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493617/looking-for-a-java-user-agent-string-parser

Comment: @fmsf I think you've totally misread the question there.

Answer (score 1):

in Windows :you can use `browse(URI uri)`  function in `Desktop` class ,it launches the default browser to display `uri`

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse("/////URI");
```