# I am running a Tomcat server, I would like to pull the details of the machine from which the requests originate. Is this possible and how?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, tcp, fingerprinting

This requirement is for a local server that collects information of all devices that connect to it in a closed organization. Need to pull details like OS Version, software versions, hardware properties.

Comment: There are some commercial products do that (e.g. http://www.mcafee.com/in/products/epolicy-orchestrator.aspx) BUT they deploy agents on the client. As you mentioned these are supposed to be used in a closed organization, where computers are controlled by administrator and user are given limited access to computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is the [user agent string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) that is in the header of all HTTP requests. You can access it via the `HttpServletRequest` like this:

```
String agent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
```

It contains info like browser (client) name, browser version, OS, OS version etc. Although there is no guarantee that these will be complete and valid, but from the server you can't force the client to send complete and valid info about itself.

### Example

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
    Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
```

This means ([source](http://www.useragentstring.com/)):

**Mozilla:** MozillaProductSlice. Claims to be a Mozilla based user agent, which is only true for Gecko browsers like Firefox and Netscape. For all other user agents it means 'Mozilla-compatible'. In modern browsers, this is only used for historical reasons. It has no real meaning anymore

**5.0:** Mozilla version

**Windows NT 6.1:** Operating System: Windows 7

**WOW64:** (Windows-On-Windows 64-bit) A 32-bit application is running on a 64-bit processor

**AppleWebKit:** The Web Kit provides a set of core classes to display web content in windows

**537.36:** Web Kit build

**KHTML:** Open Source HTML layout engine developed by the KDE project

**like Gecko:** like Gecko...

**Chrome:** Name: Chrome

**34.0.1847.131:** Chrome version

**Safari:** Based on Safari

**537.36:** Safari build

### User Agent string analysis

About analyzing user agent strings: [Looking for a Java User Agent String Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493617/looking-for-a-java-user-agent-string-parser)

Also useragentstring.com has an [API](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php).

And there are more on the internet (Google it).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine what it would mean if any webserver could ask for arbitrary information about the computer that is connecting to it. There's software that does this, but it involves client-side software, at the very least a browser plugin.

So, on the scope of the way you ask this question, I'd say "No, this isn't possible". The underlying problem can be solved though, just in a different way than your question implies you want to go. And how this would work is way beyond the scope of a simple answer here.